# Why focus after alert will trigger onblur event in javascript?

Tags: javascript

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/XavierDouble2/3a54t6r9/5/)

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  Input: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onblur="myFunction(this)">

  <p>The blur event fires when an element has lost focus.</p>

  <script>
    function myFunction(ele) {
      alert("element has been in blur status, that's why the function is triggered");
      ele.focus();

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event): The blur event fires when an element has lost focus.

So when `myFunction` is triggered, the element has lost focus. then the alert in `myFunction` will not make it lost focus again (obviously, the element cannot lose one thing it doesn't have).

And alert will block the function until user click the OK button, is it right? After clicking OK button in alert popup, the element still doesn't have the "focus", is it right?

Then `ele.focus()` will be triggered, now the element have focus again.

But you can try it in jsfiddle, there will be an infinite loop of `alert("The onblur event occurs when an object loses focus.")`, which means onblur event should have been triggered **even if you don't do anything**.

It's really confusing, what caused the 2nd time onblur event triggered???

Comment: Better question why use `alert()`, `prompt()`, or `confirm()` at all? `dialog` tag might be more work but it's worth learning. If you are using one of the three evils for testing, always use the console instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple,
because you do not let the element blur. this element is in the focus state until you click on the Alerts "OK" button. After clicking on the "Ok" button it's losing focus and triggers the `onblur` again It goes to the focus state and shows the alert. Again.....

Comment: "This element is in the focus state until you click on the Alerts "OK" button", but the MDN describe that blur event fires when an element has lost focus. The "has lost", the Present Perfect Tense, means when event fires, focus has been lost. Otherwise the definition is wrong.

Comment: That definition is correct. As I mentioned, you were simply setting focus back on your element with `ele.focus()`.

Comment: yes, I set focus back, but then even if I don't do anything, the alert will still be alerted..... emmm... so alert will not block `ele.focus()` until Ok button is clicked? the `ele.focus` has been executed before I click the OK button in alert popup, causing this issue?

Comment: you can try reload the js fiddle window and comment out the `ele.focus()` and press run, Then you will see after focus lost the input the alert shows once only. that means `ele.focus()` executed immediately after alert show.

Comment: when you keep `ele.focus()` in your blur function then its only triggers on `onblur`, 
Alert dialog opened does not mean your focus on the alert, its still remains on the input but the browser does not allow you to interact with elements while the alert is opened. When you clicking `OK` input field lose focus and call the blur function

Comment: "Alert dialog opened does not mean your focus on the alert, its still remains on the input"          --> when alert dialog is opened, myFunction has been triggered, so onblur event fires, so the input **has** lost focus. If "its still remains on the input" is right, then the definition of onblur in MDN have to be wrong.

Comment: It **has** lost focus. It remains on the input, if you tell him so. And in your code, you did say "I want to give focus back to my input element, and I will do so by writing this line of code -  `ele.focus()` .  That's the thing you have to understand, if you tell the program to give focus back, it will, but the alert will technically close and open every time you press OK. I've said it in my answer, if you remove `ele.focus()`, and try doing what you wanted, it will work.

Comment: not actually, MDN is right. 
[1] *after losing focus*, your function is called to execute and enter inside your function and start executing line by line,  your function has a total of 2 lines in the body. in line 11 it shows the alert and in line 12 it focus the input by calling `ele.focus()` 
now input is focused 
you clicked OK button input loses focus ,

*after losing focus*, ......[1]

Comment: @Arif Thanks your answer first... so when `alert(...)` is executed, the input does have lost its focus, right? But `alert` doesn't block `ele.focus()` executed, making when I click the OK button, the behavior make input lose focus again?

Comment: no, when `alert(...)` executed input **does not lose focus**, when you click `OK` button **input loses focus** and execute `onblur`

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `ele.focus()`, and it will work as you desire.

I'll try to describe step by step:

1. onblur calls the `myFunction`
2. `myFunction` executes, which results in opening the alert window
3. If you leave the `ele.focus()` inside the function, **the focus is
   set back** on the input element, basically in the same event as the
   alert window pops out
4. You press OK, and the alert window will close
5. But, since the focus is already back on the input element, the alert window goes in infinite loop, going back to step 1.

If you remove `ele.focus()` from your code, there won't be 3. and 5. step, and everything will work fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  Input: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onblur="myFunction(this)">

  <p>The blur event fires when an element has lost focus.</p>

  <script>
    function myFunction(ele) {
      alert("element has been in blur status, that's why the function is triggered");
      

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:** Here is a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4d7c5zqt/) with `console.log` included, so you can see that it triggers each time you click OK button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but to remove the `ele.focus()` will result in different result. For example, First the cursor is in the input box, and then I click, for example, on the "blur" word in the below line. At this moment, the alert will popup, after I clicked the OK button, if the `ele.focus()` exists, then the cursor will be back into the input. If there  is no `ele.focus()`, the cursor will appear in the word "blur".

Comment: @ildvzg68472 You want to say that the cursor appears in the paragraph? I don't see how is that possible